# Android Embeddable Webserver

Tags: android

I am trying to make an embeddable webserver for android, to download and upload files, more functionality will be added later.

So far I have implemented nanoHTTPD to allow navigating the directories, and downloading files.

The problem is nanoHTTPD does not have any form of authentication, or SSL
I have tried looking into implementing I-jetty,tjws,simple but cannot find any examples to work off.

Basically i am looking for an embeddable webserver than can do authentication and SSL, as well as navigate directories.

Is there a library with examples and documentation i can use? If not then how hard would it be to write one using the apache http client library.

EDIT: While checking out the source code for nanoHTTPD, i noticed the use of SSLServerSocket, and decided to listen in on traffic over a port running nanoHTTPD, and the traffic seemed encrypted, just jibberish. Unless tcpflow is not the right tool to use

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is looking for an answer.

Lighthttpd is a web server written in c/c++ that can be compiled for arm. It provides great performance as well as security and flexibility.

One benefit is it can be coupled with php-cgi to get php working on the phone as well.

https://www.lighttpd.net

I discovered this all could be done because of the open source project DroidPHP.

https://github.com/DroidPHP/DroidPHP

Comment: how to port lighttpd web server in android. Can you please suggest me? I have installed MyDroidPHP on my device.